# How can I add a InterBase JDBC connection pool in GlassFish V3?

Tags: jdbc, glassfish, interbase

Using: InterBase 2007, latest interclient.jar (8.1.8), GlassFish v3 b68.

I try to configure the connection pool in the web admin console page "Edit Connection Pool" with these settings:

- Resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource
- Datasource Classname: interbase.interclient.DataSource

A 'ping' in the same screen returns this error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: "null"
>   interbase.interclient.Connection.(Unknown
>   Source)
>   interbase.interclient.DataSource.getConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>   interbase.interclient.DataSource.getConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102)
>   com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getManagedConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:517)
>   com.sun.enterprise.connec...

The interclient.jar 8.1.8 (Interbase 2007) is in the domain lib directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is not clear, but that's an implementation detail. At least, the `getConnection()` usually expects a non-null JDBC URL. So, did you specify a valid JDBC URL for the datasource?

Comment: The same URL works fine in a simple JDBC test. I will accept you answer so that the points will not be lost ;)