# How to add an Interbase connection pool to glassfish?

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, ejb-3.0, interbase

I am attempting to add an Interbase connection pool to [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/) v3 to use EJB 3.1 in a project. The glassfish log appears to be connecting to my database properly, it spits out all my table names and indices. However, I get an error

`INFO: fetching database metadata
SEVERE: could not complete schema update
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at interbase.interclient.ResultSet.local_Close(Unknown Source)
...`

And when I ping the connection pool from within Glassfish I receive "Ping failed Exception - null".

I have the following properties set with my connectionpool:
resource type: javax.sql.DataSource
Datasource Classname: interbase.interclient.DataSource
portNumber: 3050
as well as my database info.

I can't seem to find information elsewhere. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624779/how-can-i-add-a-interbase-jdbc-connection-pool-in-glassfish-v3) question is similar but did not receive an answer.

thanks.

Comment: partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624779/how-can-i-add-a-interbase-jdbc-connection-pool-in-glassfish-v3 - but it contains additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ping fails at the connection pool level then things are very likely not going to work. Any chances to use another database? If yes, really **do it** because Interbase seems to be an outdated product and I'm not very confident with the quality of available JDBC drivers (drivers listed in [this page](http://developers.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers/search_results.jsp?jdbc_version=0&vendor_name=&cert_mode=or&jdbc_driver_type_mode=and&dbms=36&dbms_mode=and&features_mode=and&results_per_page=20&submit=Search) are all so old and dusty). It looks like time has been suspended with J2EE 1.3... If not, then maybe try another driver (the Firebird one for example).

**Update:** As pointed out by Craig in a comment, InterBase **is** maintained by [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/) and includes a Type 4 JDBC Driver. But, still, the Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero products are IMHO on a dying trend.

Comment: defintitely a possibility, up to the boss in the end though. I am currently trying to get postgres working, do you know anything about Sybase? reccomend it? DB2? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @kgrad PostgreSQL is a very nice open source product. In the commercial world, Sybase is not the leader but it's great (MS SQL Server use the same engine). DB2 is not very friendly but definitely good. Any of those products are alive and would be better than Interbase IMHO. The final choice is often not only a technical choice though.

Comment: InterBase is actively maintained and includes a maintained, type 4 JDBC driver. If it's not working for a specific case, support is available from Embarcadero. Unfortunately, he doesn't say if he's using the current version or an old one.